# Hibernate Predicate search in joined table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, predicates

I have 2 Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Organization {
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization")
    public Collection<Tin> tin;
}

@Entity
public class Tin {
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID", nullable = false)
    public Organization organization;
}
```

I want to search Organization by Tin name using CriteriaBuilder and predicates

For search I want to have list of predicates

```
List<Predicate> getPredicates() {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    ....
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(orgSearchCriteria.getTaxIdNumber())) {
                CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

                CriteriaQuery<Tin> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tin.class);
                Root<Tin> companyRoot = criteria.from( Tin.class );
                predicates.add(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(companyRoot.join("tin").get("name"), orgSearchCriteria.getName())
                );
            }
    ....
    return predicates

}
```

Comment: have you  tried something to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this one : 

                CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
                CriteriaQuery<Tin> criteria =     criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tin.class);
                Root<Tin> companyRoot = criteria.from( Tin.class );
                predicates.add(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(companyRoot.join("tin").get("tin"), orgSearchCriteria.getTaxIdNumber())
                );

Comment: please share your code so we get some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your case

```
root = criteriaQuery.from(Organization.class);
Join<Organization, Set<Tin>> resource = root.join("tin");
criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(root);
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(resource.get(NAME_COLUMN), "name");
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks 
This solved my problem 
but with this
builder.createQuery(Organization.class).distinct(true);